# How to verify a post request signature using flask/python when documentation is in Ruby

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to validate a post request signature and so far the signature hash is not matching the test hash i'm generating through my flask api.

The docs list the following code to verify the signature in Ruby

```
payload_body = request.body.read

signature = "sha1=" + OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha1"), SECRET_TOKEN, payload_body)
```

This is what I have put together so far in Flask/Python 3.6:

```
import hashlib, hmac

data=request.get_data()
key=SECRET_TOKEN.encode("utf-8"))
signature = "sha1=" + hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
```

With the following data:

SECRET_TOKEN=""

request_data={"type": "verification_approved","data":{"level":"v1","user_id":"d6d782ef-568b-4355-8eb4-2d32ac97b44c"}}

They obtain :

Ruby hash: "sha1=2e7c4e307e25dd0ce4baad4d90dc7d4b63bdbab6" # as indicated in the documentation

I obtain:

Python hash: "sha1=b9361bca2a38228c741ef60296b468693752b76d" # my implementation

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Official doc is here: https://docs.developer.fractal.id/user-integration/webhooks/securing-webhooks and https://docs.developer.fractal.id/user-integration/webhooks/delivery

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation you're referencing? Some additional context might be helpful.

Comment: https://docs.developer.fractal.id/user-integration/webhooks/delivery and https://docs.developer.fractal.id/user-integration/webhooks/securing-webhooks

Comment: Try using Flask's `request.data` instead of `request.get_data`. Maybe it's messing with how the JSON is encoded/adding escape characters when converting it to a string (which would obviously mess up the resulting hash).

Comment: Tried request.data and request.stream.read() but nothing

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation given, this is how I would implement such a HMAC SHA1 signature validation (this is very similar to how GitHub does webhooks, and this implementation works there, but I've updated the headers to match what you're expecting):

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1

from flask import request, abort

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook(request):
    if "X-Fractal-Signature" not in request.headers:
        abort(403)
    signature = request.headers.get("X-Fractal-Signature", "").split("=")[1]

    # Generate our own signature based on the request payload
    secret = os.environ.get('FRACTAL_SECRET', '').encode("utf-8")
    mac = hmac.new(secret, msg=request.data, digestmod=sha1)

    # Ensure the two signatures match
    if not str(mac.hexdigest()) == str(signature):
        abort(403)
```

They abort a 400 in the documentation, personally I'd use a 403s instead.

Comment: Thx for the answer! However, my problem does not lie in the flask implementation. What you suggest would yield the same result as mine for the signature given the example payload and secret token: b9361bca2a38228c741ef60296b468693752b76d. But the official doc finds: 2e7c4e307e25dd0ce4baad4d90dc7d4b63bdbab6. Thx again for your very welcome help

Comment: Running their own Ruby example (or dumping the secret/payload in to an online HMAC generator) does not result in the SHA1 they provide in their example, and given their docs say they're very much a WIP, I'm willing to bet it's just a bad example. The above is a working Flask example for another webhook validation that meets the same criteria, so I'd go with that and see if it fails on integration—if it does, I think you'll need to take that up with them.

Comment: Pretty sure the correct hash should be ba213ac630ca4e30446a923fdd1fa78655902880, which is what the example I've given you would lend.